# How can I create the kernel headers for ARM on X86?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cross-compilation, linux-headers

I have an ARM-based board, which I used with factory kernel (5.10.110).

To manually build a kernel module, I needed the kernel-header package. To install this package it was explained in the [documentation](https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPi_R5C#Install_the_kernel-header_package):

> sudo dpkg -i /opt/linux-headers-*.deb

This created the below structure:

```
/lib/modules/5.10.110$ ls -la
total 1584
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Apr 29 15:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Jul 10 21:36 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 Feb 20 07:05 build -> /usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.110
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Feb 20 13:29 extra
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Feb 20 13:29 kernel
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 327270 Apr 29 15:13 modules.alias
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 346627 Apr 29 15:13 modules.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  28645 Feb 20 13:29 modules.builtin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Apr 29 15:13 modules.builtin.alias.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  30656 Apr 29 15:13 modules.builtin.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 164216 Feb 20 13:29 modules.builtin.modinfo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  95077 Apr 29 15:13 modules.dep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 153551 Apr 29 15:13 modules.dep.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    140 Apr 29 15:13 modules.devname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  51432 Feb 20 13:29 modules.order
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    468 Apr 29 15:13 modules.softdep
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 163120 Apr 29 15:13 modules.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 206275 Apr 29 15:13 modules.symbols.bin
```

Now I had to recompile the whole kernel and version is increased from 5.10.110 to **5.10.160**.

So now, when I try to compile a kernel module it is not finding the required headers.

Build folder contains these files in 5.10.110:

```
/lib/modules/5.10.110/build$ ls -la
total 1364
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root    4096 Jul 10 22:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  220133 Feb 20 07:05 .config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   68886 Dec  1  2022 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1075160 Feb 20 07:02 Module.symvers
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:03 arch
drwxr-xr-x 31 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:03 include
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root   12288 Apr 29 15:03 scripts
```

How can I recreate these headers for building custom kernel modules against my new kernel of version 5.10.160?

I made various trials: copying these folders from my computer where I cross-compiled the kernel: not working, as "scripts" folder contains machine code (x86_64) which is not executing on aarch64.

Then I copied "scripts" folder from 5.10.110, but I'm unsure if it's okay, or will cause harm or unwanted results.

So how could I cross-compile the environment for building custom kernel modules?

Comment: "*I needed the kernel-header package*-- You have an ARM-based board, but you are probably using an Intel-based PC host to perform this module building with a cross-compiler/toolchain.  Your `dpkg` command fetched and installed the headers of the Linux distro installed for your PC host. But you need the headers for the kernel used by your ARM-based board. You seem to be making a mess by co-mingling code.

Comment: Yes, so that the question is about how can I create the kernel headers for ARM on X86?

Answer (score 2):

> I have an ARM-based board, which I used with factory kernel (5.10.110).
>
> To manually build a kernel module, I needed the kernel-header package.

You have an ARM-based board, but you are probably using an Intel-based PC host to perform this module building with a cross-compiler/toolchain. Your `dpkg` command fetched and installed the headers of the Linux distro installed for your PC host. But you need the headers for the kernel version used by your ARM-based board.

---

First you need to download the tarball of the specific kernel version, i.e. 5.10.110. You neglect to mention if this is a mainline version of the Linux kernel, or a version with modifications by a chip or board manufacturer.

Source code for the mainline versions of the Linux kernel are available from the [Linux Kernel Archives](https://www.kernel.org/). The tarball of mainline version 5.10.110 is [here (in gzip compression)](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.10.110.tar.gz).

Regardless, obtain/download the appropriate source code.
Unarchive and install this source tree completely separate from your PC's distro installation. Suggest you use a development directory under **/home** for your cross compilation tasks.

---

Once you have the required version of the kernel source in a subdirectory, you will be able to export that kernel's header files using the `make headers_install` command from the shell.
Refer to [this guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/headers_install.txt):

```
Exporting kernel headers for use by userspace
=============================================

The "make headers_install" command exports the kernel's header files in a
form suitable for use by userspace programs.
...

The "make headers_install" command can be run in the top level directory of the
kernel source code (or using a standard out-of-tree build).  It takes two
optional arguments:

  make headers_install ARCH=i386 INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr
```

Again, I suggest that you install these headers that are unrelated to your host system and used for cross-compiling somewhere more local, such as a development directory under **/home** (i.e. do not blindly use the above example).

Comment: Are you sure this will compile the binaries in "scripts" folder ?